# virtualenv + apt-get confusion

Tags: python, virtualenv

I've started using virtualenv and I have a doubt, any hint will be welcome.

This is my scenario:

1. I active virtualenv and install a package XXX (using apt-get) that deploy some python stuff in my virtualenv/site-packages.
2. Deactivate virtualenv
3. Run apt-get upgrade XXX

What happen in this case with the XXX's python stuff? It's installed in the global site-packages? Can something be broken?

Sorry if it's a silly question, but deployment of python packages is a bit blur for me :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `apt-get`, packages will always get installed system-wide, not in the virtualenv. This, regardless of whether a virtualenv is currently active.

In your case, that means that the package is installed system-wide in 1, and that install is upgraded in 3.

If you want to install something in the virtualenv, the closer you can get to `apt-get` is using [`pip`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip):

---

Example:

```
virtualenv ENV
source ENV/bin/activate
pip install django
```

Django is now installed in the virtualenv at `./ENV`, but not system-wide.

Conversely, doing: `apt-get install python-django` would install it system-wide, but not in the virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but according to http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/#activate-script when you do `source bin/activate` you are changing $PATH to point to virtualenv, how can apt-get deploy python files system-wide instead of deploy them in my local environment?

Comment: @fcrazy Quite simply: `apt-get` doesn't remotely care about your `$PATH`. `apt-get` installs stuff to where it belongs on the system, and that's not up to you where that is : ) `pip` is the tool you want to be using here, don't worry though, it's very easy to use!

Comment: @fcrazy You might want to have a look here, for more detail on where `apt-get` installs files: http://askubuntu.com/questions/165361/how-to-set-the-path-where-sudo-apt-get-installs